# Why can I not change window title with mintty/wsl

Tags: terminal, cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I started mintty of cygwin, and run following commands :

```
~$ # here, we are in cygwin/bash
~$ printf "\e]0;cygwin\7"
~$ # Now I see "cygwin" on mintty's title
~$ wsl
~$ # now, we are in wsl/bash/debian
~$ printf "\e]0;wsl\7"
~$ # No change in mintty's title
```

wsl = Windows Subsystem for Linux

**Solved**

I found this terminal which is based on mintty, and escape sequence for changing window title works correctly.

[wsl-terminal](https://github.com/goreliu/wsl-terminal)

Comment: What do you get in the two environment if you do `echo $PWD` (edit question)?

Comment: Not what I meant, but it tells us something (better than I intended). What terminal are you using? Is it the same in both environments?

Comment: mintty is the cygwin terminal, like CMD in windows. The code I pasted is a single session. https://mintty.github.io/

Comment: I know it: It is the CMD terminal, but with a different shell running in it.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's CMD terminal with different shell ruinning.  It's like xterm, gnome-terminal and Mac Terminal are different terminals.

Comment: Well the same terminal that cmd uses (can cmd use a different terminal?). If so then can you specify which one you are using?

Comment: Have you followed https://github.com/mintty/wsltty and installed it ? I doubt you should run WSL from within a Cygwin bash (Disclaimer: I do not use WSL)

Comment: @matzeri I usually don't start wsl from within Cygwin bash, I start directly from mintty with `mintty -e wsl`. I know wsltty, but I'm so used to mintty, with font, shift-insert which are missing in wsltty. Do you use Cygwin ? I recommend to migrate to wsl which is much faster.

Comment: I suspect the only thing faster is fork. Does X server works in wsl ?

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer instead of editing the question./

Answer (score 0):

I found this terminal which is based on mintty, and escape sequence for changing window title works correctly.

[wsl-terminal](https://github.com/goreliu/wsl-terminal)